# What is the best approach to work with BLE device in background?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently I am working on an application which has BLE peripheral, my app works as master and the BLE device works as peripheral.

**The app has below mentioned use cases:**

1. The application should connect and communicate with the BLE device even if the app is not in foreground. (app can be in background or closed)
2. Once the app is connected to the BLE device we need to get the data in our application and process on it.
3. So the basic use case which needs to be achieved is, once the BLE device is in our device's range it should connect and communicate with our app
   , whereas once its out of our device's range it should stop the communication process.

All these things should work well even if our app is in background or closed state.

As per the background limitations from oreo as mentioned in this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background 
, we can not use services to achieve this scenario.

Currently we are using **foreground services** to achieve the desired use case, but not sure if that is the best approach to work with.

Please let me know the best approach which can be used to achieve the above mentioned use case using the latest android api.

**Note:** Our app has minimum sdk version 23 and target sdk version 28

Comment: Firstly, there is nothing best in programming. As for foreground service, it is the only way to make the app work in background. Also to scan devices all the time, you will likely have to acquire wakelock, which will prevent device from deep sleep, which means the battery will run out fast. That is the cost of being able to do tasks in background at any time

Comment: You do not need a wake lock to have pending initiating BLE connections using autoConnect=true since that work is done by the Bluetooth chip and not the main CPU. And I would also say that Foreground Service is the only acceptable option in this case. You could scan in the background using the new PendingIntent feature (no need for a Foreground service in that case) and then connect when you find a device, but the scan parameters are so bad that it might take minutes to discover the device that way.

Comment: Can I anyhow use Workmanager or Job scheduler for this use case? Is it reliable?

Comment: @Emil We are connecting the BLE in foreground first time, and we have also kept the autoConnect flag to **true**, we basically wants to communicate with BLE after that, even if the app is in background. As I said, if the BLE device is in our device's range it should communicate with our app , whereas once its out of our device's range we want to stop the communication process. Can you please suggest me an approach for it?

Comment: Do you mean after it disconnects, your app should stop and no longer try to connect again (even when it comes back in range)?

Comment: No, it should connect and communicate again once the BLE device is in range.

Comment: @Emil In current scenario, we are using foreground services to monitor the BLE, what I want to achieve is that, we should be notified and should stop monitoring if the BLE is no more connected to our device(i.e. when it goes out of range) and again when it comes in range, I want to get notified and start monitoring the BLE for the latest data.
So rather than using Foreground services to continuously monitor it, can we use anything else as an alternative and a better and reliable approach.

Comment: I don't know anything better than Foreground Service in combination with autoConnect=true unless you can accept minutes of latency for detection.

Comment: @Emil Okay. So what approach you suggest if a delay in detection is fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194412/discussion-between-darshna-desai-and-emil).